# TableRow added programmatically to a TableLayout does not display

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I'm trying to add rows to a TableLayout  programmatically, but they are not displayed.Displays only the header of the table, which is created on layout.

My TableLayout:

```
            <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/resultTable"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="#000"
            android:stretchColumns="1">

            <TableRow android:padding="1dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#cccccc"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="№"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:background="#cccccc"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Вопрос"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:background="#cccccc"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Результат"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
```

Code:

```
 TableLayout resultTable=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.resultTable);
    int  i=1;
    for (Question q:questions)
    {
        resultTable.addView(buildTableRow(""+i,q.getText(),resultExamMap.get(q.getId())));
        i++;
    }
```

These methods create TableRow, which I add in TableLayout:

```
private TextView buildTableColumn(String text,int color)
{
    TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(1,0,0,0);
    TextView column=new TextView(this);
    column.setBackgroundColor(color);
    column.setText(text);
    return  column;
}
private TableRow buildTableRow(String textCol1,String textCol2,boolean isTrue)
{
    TableRow   tableRow=new TableRow(this);
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tableRow.addView(buildTableColumn(textCol1,0xcccccc));
    tableRow.addView(buildTableColumn(textCol2,0xcccccc));
    if(isTrue) {
        tableRow.addView(buildTableColumn("True",0x00ff00));
    }
    else{
        tableRow.addView(buildTableColumn("False",0xff0000));
    }
    return tableRow;
}
```

Thanks.